# Рекурсивный запрос в postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, рекурсия

Есть такая таблица   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо получить иерархию в виде [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал рекурсивный запрос

```
with  recursive rec(scopename , parentname ) as (
   select scopename , parentname  from _geoimage_scope 
   union all
   select rec.scopename , rec.parentname  from rec,_geoimage_scope where rec.scopename = _geoimage_scope.parentname
)

select * from rec where parentname is null
```

Но не выходит,  получается бесконечная рекурсия. Кто может подсказать, помочь? Пользуюсь  postgresql

Answer (score 2):

У Вас получился бесконечный запрос потому, что (представим пример на одной из записей):

1. На первом шаге Вы отобрали запись `scopename='utilitiesconsumption'` И теперь в `rec` находится эта одна запись.
2. На втором шаге Вы берете полученную запись и делаете запрос вида (примерно)

`select rec.scopename, rec.parentname
    from
    (
      select cast('utilitiesconsumption' as text) scopename, null parentname 
    ) rec, _geoimage_scope
    where rec.scopename = _geoimage_scope.parentname`

Который возвращает Вам точно такую же запись, что сейчас есть в `rec`, только, в Вашем случае, четыре раза. 
Получается, что теперь у Вас в `rec` находится 5 одинаковых записей.

3. На третьем шаге Вы берете следующую запись из `rec` и, т.к. она у Вас точно такая же как и первая запись, то полностью повторяется шаг 2. В результате чего количество записей в `rec` становится уже 9 (и все они одинаковые) и так до бесконечности.

Вам должен помочь такой запрос:

```
with recursive rec(scopename, parentname ) 
as 
( 
  select scopename, parentname 
  from _geoimage_scope
  where parentname is null
  union all 
  select _geoimage_scope.scopename, _geoimage_scope.parentname 
  from _geoimage_scope, rec where _geoimage_scope.parentname = rec.scopename 
)
select * from rec
```

Тестовый пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d8724/1)